# SQL comparison operators

Tags: sql

are these two statements the same?

query 1:  `WHERE salary > 999;`

query 2:  `WHERE salary >= 1000;`

I thought they were, but apparently according to my peers they are not (Though they have failed to explain why).

Comment: your peers don't know much, and i don't think it's a very good question

Comment: @IbrahimDiallo I think you know less than his/her peers :)

Comment: @oscar is it going to give the same result? if so then ....

Comment: @IbrahimDiallo Did you think about what would happen if you are talking about numbers with comma? `salary >= 1000` means that `salary > 999.50`, and that's not always true with just saying `salary > 999`.

Comment: @IbrahimDiallo well I used peer instead of my lecturer. Because a question like this was on the exam, and I said it was the same. The question didn't specify the datatype, but I assumed it was INT as the question was talking about offspring. I got it wrong.

Comment: The database vendor can influence data types, and thus how such comparisons would occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not necessarily the same. If you're storing doubles, when you do:

```
WHERE salary >= 1000;
```

you're not taking in count all values that are between `999` and `1000` (eg. `999.50`)

Otherwise, if you're working with integers, that's true, not only in programming, but also in maths.

```
n > k <=> n >= k+1
```

Answer (score 1):

The two queries will give the same results, if `salary` is an integral type. But if salary is some real type, then the results will be different.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely dependant on the datatype of salary.

If salary is an INT or a BIGINT then yes they will yield the same results.

If salary is pretty much any other datatype, the first once will return results for 999.9, but the second one won't.